# Changing the prefix of many chords

Tags: key-bindings

It just occurred to me that the org-babel prefix `C-c C-v` must be what
it is because of the proximity of `c` and `v` in qwerty, and that it
would be better for me to use `C-c C-f`.  Is there a simple way to
change the prefix for all chords using it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want to override the binding <kbd>C-c C-f</kbd> for `org-forward-heading-same-level` you can do that as follows.

```el
(defvar org-C-c-C-v (lookup-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-v"))
  "Binding of C-c C-v in Orgmode.")
(defvar org-C-c-C-f (lookup-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-f"))
  "Binding of C-c C-f in Orgmode.")

(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-f") org-C-c-C-v)
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-v") nil)
```

One could also avoid the variables `org-C-c-C-v` and `org-C-c-C-f` by substituting their values into the first `define-key` and by ignoring the value of the original binding for <kbd>C-c C-f</kbd>. The variables give you the possibility to easily switch back to the original state without reloading org.

Note that the usage of `defvar` is kind of protection of the original binding value. When you have already the modified bindings through running the code once and reevaluate the code the values of `org-C-c-C-v` and `org-C-c-C-f` are not overwritten by the new bindings because of the special behavior of `defvar` ([see its doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/defvar.html)).

You can switch back to the original bindings with:

```el
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-f") org-C-c-C-f)
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-v") org-C-c-C-v)
```